# Angularjs app improvement

Tags: angularjs

Hi all i am working on angularJS app. Everything is fine but I have only one issue. I have to **link and load(as dependency)** in my app. That's why i have this kind of code

```
<script src="shared.js"></script>
<script src="user.js"></script>
<script src="home.js"></script>
<script src="product.js"></script>
<script src="comment.js"></script>
<script src="address.js"></script>
<script src="cities.js"></script>
<script src="phone.js"></script>
<script src="review.js"></script>
<script src="configs.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

And In app.js i have these app dependies

```
'mainApp.shareModule',
'mainApp.userModule',
'mainApp.homeModule',
'mainApp.commentModule',
'mainApp.addressModule',
'mainApp.citiesModule',
'mainApp.phoneModule',
'mainApp.reviewModule',
'mainApp.productModule'
```

Is there any solution like (lazy loading) but my understanding is about lazy loading is then i have to design all modules independent.
Thank you.

Comment: what your files sizes in kB?

Comment: I would like to suggest concat and minfiy all files. it will reduce your load time.

Comment: Hi @murli2308 !
 So it means i have to add whole script in to my home(index) page ?

Comment: Hi @PetrAveryanov size is around ~1MB. I am not asking about loading problem. is is there any option to link these files separately ?

Comment: @9me yes you can add it in index page.. for lazy loading you need to use requirejs along with angularjs